# Can't solve NullSafety to test a fromJson Factory

Tags: flutter, dart, tdd, factory

I'm giving a try on Flutter but having a hard time trying to follow TDD process giving Null Safety complexity.

A made a simple test (below) for instantiating a Model but I keep getting like `Null check operator used on a null value` or `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

`token_model_test.dart`

```
void main() {
  const tTokenModel = TokenModel(tokenString: 'wefrgvwergv');

  test(
    'Should return valid token model when credentials are provided',
    () async {
      // arrange
      final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = 
        json.decode(fixture('auth.json'));

      // act
      final result = TokenModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
      
      // assert
      expect(result, tTokenModel);
    }
  );
```

`token_model.dart`

```
import 'package:griot_app/authentication/domain/entities/token.dart';

class TokenModel extends Token {
  const TokenModel({required String tokenString}) : super(tokenString: tokenString);

  factory TokenModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    dynamic mytoken = json['tokenString'];
    return TokenModel(
      tokenString: mytoken,
    );
  }
}
```

`token.dart`

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Token extends Equatable{
  final String tokenString;
  
  const Token({required this.tokenString});
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [tokenString];
}
```

I tried a couple of different random implementation for the TokenModel as follows

```
import 'package:griot_app/authentication/domain/entities/token.dart';

class TokenModel extends Token {
  const TokenModel({required String tokenString}) : super(tokenString: tokenString);

  factory TokenModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TokenModel(
      tokenString: json['tokenString'],
    );
  }
}
```

Which leads to type `'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

I was expecting to find a way to be able to test it before moving forward.

Comment: This stuff all got a lot easier with patterns.  Be sure you do the "patterns and records" codelab for dart 3.